# Is it possible to remove the Maximum call stack size?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a weird block movement thing, but after it moved 10 times it says:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

And my purpose is to let it move the whole time, here is the code BTW:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Look - The game</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="square" style="position:absolute; width:5px; height:5px; background:black"></div>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var square = document.getElementById("square");
            var duration = 1000;
            var steps = 1;
            function movesquare(){
                var randomtop = Math.floor(Math.random() * screen.height);
                var randomleft = Math.floor(Math.random() * screen.width);
                $(square).animate({marginTop:randomtop, marginLeft:randomleft}, duration, movesquare);
                duration -= steps;
                steps = steps * 2;
            }
            movesquare();
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using recursion? Perhaps this is inadvertent? This is the cause of your stack problems.

Comment: your are doing something wrong ... !

Comment: `Maximum call stack size exceeded` indicates that you have an a kind of _endless loop_ and if the browser would not stop your script, your browser most likely will become unresponsive in such a situation.

Comment: I want to get it moving the whole time, or is there an another way to do that. Here is btw the [page](http://www.blackbirdprojects.me/look.html)

Comment: Technically, all recursions can be rewritten with iterations. Since JS doesn't take care of tail recursion, you may give iteration a try. Oh by the way, looks like your code is animating endlessly, which I'm afraid isn't necessary.

Comment: @LeoDeng it's only going to be recursive when `duration` is less than or equal to zero. So long as it's greater than zero, there'll be no recursion.

Comment: @Pointy `duration -= steps`, eventually it will be...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that:

```
$(square).animate({marginTop:randomtop, marginLeft:randomleft}, duration, movesquare);
```

Will call `movesquare` immediately when `duration` is `0` or smaller.
At the time this happens you created an *endless loop*.

You need to make sure that `duration` does not become `0`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realised that the duration will became lower than 0 in 10 steps.